# Element type is invalid: expected a string in react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Full error message:

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in
> components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got:
> object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's
> defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

usually this is something to do with components not being imported or exported correctly but everything looks fine to me. Any ideas what the issue could be.

```
import React, { useRef, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import ScrollToTop from './ScollToTop';

const StoreDirectory = (props) => {

  const [filteredValues, setValues] = useState(props.storesData);
  const [initialValues, setInitialValues] = useState(props.storesData);
  const [storeCategorys, setStoreCategories] = useState(props.storesCategorysData);

  const alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  const alphabetIntoArray = alphabet.split("");

  const itemsRef = useRef([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    itemsRef.current = itemsRef.current.slice(0, alphabetIntoArray.length);
  }, [alphabetIntoArray])

  const AlphaButtons = () => {

    const goToSelection = (event, index) => {
      if(itemsRef.current[index]) {
        itemsRef.current[index].scrollIntoView({
          behaviour: "smooth",
          block: "nearest"
        })
      }
    }

    return (
      <>
        {alphabet.split("").map((item, index) => (
          <button key={index} onClick={(e) => goToSelection(e, index)}>{item}</button>
        ))}      
      </>
    )
  }

  const DropDown = () => {
    const handleOnchange = (event) => {
      const filter = event.target.id;
      const initialState = [...initialValues]
      setValues(initialState.filter(store => 
        {return (store.store-category.indexOf(filter) >= 0)}
      ));
    }

    const defaultSelectMessage = 'select a category';

    return (
      <Form>
        <Form.Group controlId="exampleForm.SelectCustom">
          <Form.Label>Custom select</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control defaultValue={defaultSelectMessage} onChange={(e) => handleOnchange(e)} as="select" custom>
            <option hidden disabled value={defaultSelectMessage}>{defaultSelectMessage}</option>
            {storeCategorys.map((item, index) => (
              <option id={item.id} key={index}>{item.name}</option>
            ))}
          </Form.Control>
        </Form.Group>
      </Form>
    );
  }

  const Filter = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        {alphabet.split("").map((c, i) => {
          return (
            <>
            {filteredValues
              .filter(store => store.title.rendered.startsWith(c)).length === 0 
              ? <h1 ref={ el => itemsRef.current[i] = el } className={'Grey'}>{c}</h1>
              : <h1 ref={ el => itemsRef.current[i] = el } className={'notGrey'}>{c}</h1>   
            }
              
            {filteredValues
              .filter(store => store.title.rendered.startsWith(c))
              .map((item, index) => (   
                <li key={index}>{item.title.rendered}</li>
              ))}
              
            </>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <>
      <DropDown />
      <AlphaButtons />
      <Filter />
      <ScrollToTop />
    </>
  )
  
}

export default StoreDirectory;
```

Comment: It's a bit of a code dump, can you not narrow down whats causing the error.  eg. try and maybe render just `<Dropdown />`, and then do the next etc..

Comment: at what line of your code you are getting the error?

Comment: WOW I fixed it. I don't want to even tell you guys what it was.